# I have implemented 2Checkout payment API?

Tags: codeigniter, api, payment-gateway, 2checkout

I have implemented 2Checkout payment API? But sometime its showing "curl call failed". Otherwise it showing "Payment Authorization Failed: Please verify your information and try again, or try another payment method." Can any one help to correct the error.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on your problem? E.g edit in the blocks of code that you're having trouble with and some more info on exactly where you think the problem is.